# D3.js color the node circles with a function using spectrum.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, spectrumjs

For each node, i have a circle which I color with the help of a function `ColorType(d)`:

```
 node.append("circle")
     .attr("r", 20)
     .attr("y", -25)
     .style("fill", function(d) { return ColorType(d); })
     .style("stroke-width",0.5)
     .style("stroke",'black')
     .attr("opacity", "1");
```

My `ColorType` function is

```
function ColorType(d){
    for (var i = 0; i < TypesTab.length; i++) {
        if (d.type == TypesTab[i].type) { return ColorAction;}
    }   
}
```

in the above function, `d.type` is the *type* of my node (see below the json file strucutre). And `TypesTab[i].type` is each of my types stored separately in **types**, checking if the node type is the same as one of the value of the type in **types**, if so then applies the `ColorAction` which colors the node circle.

and here is the `ColorAction` code, which is embedded in each color picker container that is appended to each type in types, the list which is inserted to `#filterColor` html dom. so each type has a color picker container which is supposed to color its own type only.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("databeta.json", function (obj) {
        $('#filterColor').data('types', obj.types.map(function (o) {
            // console.log(o.type);
            return o.type;
        })).append(obj.types.map(function (o) {
            return '<li>' + o.type + '<input class="color-picker" type="text"/></li>';
        }).join(''));

        var data = $('#filterColor').data('types'); //stores all types

        mynodes = obj.nodes;
        console.log("mynodes : ", mynodes); //array of all my nodes
        console.log("mynodes : ", mynodes[3].type); //reading the type of the fourth object in the nodes array

        $("#filterColor .color-picker").each(function(){
            $(this).spectrum({
                color: (function (m, s, c) {
                    return (c ? arguments.callee(m, s, c - 1) : '#') +
                        s[m.floor(m.random() * s.length)]
                })(Math, '0123456789ABCDEF', 5), //generate random initial color for each container
                preferredFormat: "rgb",
                showInput: true,
                showPalette: true,
                showAlpha: true,
                palette: [["red", "rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)"]],
                change: function(color) {
                    MyNode = d3.select("#node").selectAll(".entreprise").select("circle");
                    MyNode.style("fill", function(d) {
                        return d3.rgb(color.toHexString())
                    });
                    Coloration = d3.rgb(color.toHexString());
                }
            });
        });

    });
});
```

the problem is that when i hardcode the type in the `ColorType(d)` function,

```
if (d.type == "school") { return ColorAction;}
```

it successfully colors the **school** typed nodes only. However, if i want to make it dynamic so that it colors the nodes with the type that the color picker is assigned to, it fails, because I can't make the connection with the `each` of `o.type`. So the question is to pass the `each` of `o.type` into the `ColorAction` and/or `ColorType(d)` so that each container only colors the nodes of its own type.

Here is an unsuccessfull attempt, because it doesn't take into consideration the `o.type` and reads the `type` in **types** from a global variable (`TypesTab`) that holds all `type`s in **types**:

```
function ColorType(d){
    for (var i = 0; i < TypesTab.length; i++) {
        if (d.type == TypesTab[i].type) { return ColorAction;}
    }

}
```

The below is the json structure:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
        "type": "school",
        "country": "US",
        "name": "saint peter's",
        "id": 1006
        },
        {
        "type": "univeristy",
        "country": "Brazil",
        "name": "saint joseph's",
        "id": 1007
        }        
        ...
    ],
    "links": [
            {
            "source": 1006,
            "target": 1007,
            "value": 20            
        },
       ...

    ],
    "types": [
                {
                    "type": "school",
                    "image": "image01"
                },
                {
                    "type": "univeristy",
                    "image": "image02"
                },
                {
                    "type": "company",
                    "image": "image03"
                },
                ...
            ]   
}
```

Comment: Its probably not the answer but in general you should use === instead of == in comparisons. If == has not hurt you yet it definitely will. Why - because === tests for both equal value and equal type. See this SO post for an explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: You have posted a lot of information which can be useful but in this case it masks the issue. Can you break the issue down to a pithy example?

Comment: OK so you're JSON is incorrectly formatted you have an extra ***comma ,*** after  ` {
      "type": "company",
      "image": "image03"
    },`
JSON standard does not allow trailing comma

Comment: And JSON at line 15 ***...***  ',' or ']' expected, got '.'

Comment: Also why are you using  $.getJSON why not use d3's built-in function d3.json() to import the data? In fact you are using a lot of jQuery where you might be better to use just d3.js functions?

Comment: @theWhiteFox actually the training commas are my fault when trying to build my example to post here, in the real file there is no such thing, it is a valid json file. can you suggest a way to read the json file using the d3 lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how I would read / import JSON. Inside the for in is basic, so you would need to change that part to suit your needs.

`d3.json("data.json", function (error, data) {
    console.log(d3.values(data));  // do this as a check
     for (var d in data) {
            d.nodes = +d.nodes;
            d.links = +d.links;
            d.types = +d.types;
        }
    // svg can go here
})`

Comment: i get `TypeError: data.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @jacky OK so my mistake try a for in instead of a forEach loop. Also this is a great [free d3.js charts book](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks)

Comment: there is an error again, anyway this is not the answer that directly solves th question. would you provide a working answer to the question